# What is the default color used for NavigationBar in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigationbar, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet, bottom-navigation-bar

I have a `NavigationBar` in my app and occasionally I will show a modal bottom sheet.
I would like the bottom sheet to have the same color as the `NavigationBar`.
What is the default color for the `NavigationBar`, hence for the modal bottom sheet?

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  context: _scaffoldKey.currentContext!,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return BottomSheetComponent(marker: marker);
  },
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the default colors of a Flutter widget from the docs or from the source code.

From the documentation, the [`backgroundColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationBar/backgroundColor.html) property of `NavigationBar` is described as:

> The color of the NavigationBar itself.
>
> If null, NavigationBarThemeData.backgroundColor is used. If that is also null, then if ThemeData.useMaterial3 is true, the value is ColorScheme.surface. If that is false, the default blends ColorScheme.surface and ColorScheme.onSurface using an ElevationOverlay.

You can get `ColorScheme` from `Theme.of(context).colorScheme`. For example, to get the `ColorScheme.onSurface` value you can do this:

```dart
Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface
```

---

If you're asking about the source of the tinted color that applies on the `NavigationBar`, that is from the [surfaceTintColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationBar/surfaceTintColor.html) property.

Comment: I have read that. It reads the color of the navigation bar itself. But where does that color comes from in the first place?

Comment: It is described in the second paragraph. The color is determined based on some conditions, and results in different use of elements from `ColorScheme`. You can read about `ColorScheme` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ColorScheme-class.html)

Comment: Or are you looking for the source of the tinted color? That is from the [surfaceTintColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationBar/surfaceTintColor.html) property

Comment: I haven't defined a `navigationBarTheme` in my ThemeData so all the `NavigationBarThemeData` properties are null. I was looking for how flutter then calculates the color when using material3 in order to apply it to the bottom sheet color as well.

Comment: Yes, it is as mentioned in the docs. For example, if the docs mentioned `ColorScheme.onSurface`, then you can get the same color by using this: `Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface`